# PHP Callback function return outer function

Tags: php, callback, return

I have a function and within this function I'm using a function with a callback. And in this callback function I want to return the outer function (isRunning). How can I do that? Because right now the returns in my callback function are only for the callback function and not for the isRunning function.

```
public static function isRunning($instance){
    $commands = [
        'systemctl is-active myservice'.$instance->id
    ];

    SSH::run($commands, function ($line) {
        if($line == 'inactive'){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

This is code for my Laravel application btw.

Comment: The callback is synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: I think its asynchrnous. It's the run function from this class: https://github.com/LaravelCollective/remote/blob/5.6/src/Connection.php

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
public static function isRunning($instance){
    $commands = [
        'systemctl is-active myservice'.$instance->id
    ];

    $isRunning = null;
    SSH::run($commands, function ($line) use (&$isRunning) {
        if(trim($line) == 'active'){
            $isRunning = true;
        }
        elseif(trim($line) == 'inactive'){
            $isRunning = false;
        }
    });
    return $isRunning;
}
```